# How to show $\,2^n \equiv 8\pmod{24}\,$ for odd $\,n\ge 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $n\geq3$ is odd, then $2^n-1\equiv7\mod24$.

I tried solving this backwardly. We want to prove that $2^3(2^{n-3}-1)=2^n-2^3\equiv0\mod24$. Since $\frac{24}{2^3}=3$, this leaves us to prove that $3\mid2^{n-3}-1$. From here on I got stuck, although I feel like I am ignoring something very simple.

Once the result is proved, I need to find all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ for which $2^n-1$ divides $3^n-1$.

This problem is given in a chapter on the Legendre symbol, introducing the law of quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Please post a separate question for the second problem for better attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $n$ is odd, so writing $n=2k+1$ gives
$$2^{n-3}-1\equiv 2^{2k-2}-1\equiv (2^2)^{k-1}-1\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ 2^{\overbrace{\large 3+2k}^{\LARGE n}}\bmod 24\, =\, 2^{\large 3}(\overbrace{\color{#c00}2^{\large\color{#c00} 2k}\!\bmod 3}^{\large \color{#c00}{2^{\LARGE 2}}\ \equiv\  1})\, =\, 2^{\large 3}\ $

We used: $\,\ ab\bmod ac\, =\, a(b\bmod c)\,= $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor $\,a = 2^{\large 3}$ out of the mod.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now also learned a new law in modular arithmetic!

Comment: @bitsbit Great. MDL is usually the quickest way to do these type of problems (it yields an *operational* way to apply CRT, as I explain in the linked answer). The little time spent learning it will reap much greater time savings in future analogous calculations.

Answer (score 1):

In one hand, since $n\geq 3$ then $8|2^n$, i.e. $2^n\equiv 0\bmod 8$. Hence $$2^n-1\equiv 7\mod 8$$

On the other hand, since $n$ is odd, we have $2^n\equiv(-1)^n=-1\bmod 3$. Hence, $2^n-1\equiv -2\bmod 3$. In particular $$2^n-1\equiv 7\mod 3.$$

So, we conclude $2^n-1\equiv 7\mod 24.$

Comment: Thank you! This is a very neat answer.